# How to make multiple pop up div based on database information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I recently learned about Jquery pop-up div.
I used [this link](http://creativeindividual.co.uk/2011/02/create-a-pop-up-div-in-jquery/).
I want that kind of pop up div.

But the problem is , I need multiple  pop-up div.
Suppose i have 15 user in database table then i want 15 different link.
Moreover every popup div should show the database information of that user.

I also found [this one](http://creativeindividual.co.uk/2011/08/create-multiple-pop-up-divs-using-the-jquery-prev-method/), but this pop-up div doesn't move with the mouse pointer and when the div width greater than the link width this doesn't work.

So i want pop-up div like the first example.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this problem diferently than you. So here's my idea.

1st- you don't need multiple divs cuz using jquery & php you can manipulate a single div however you want.
2nd- saying you display your 15 persons 1st makes the job easier. Let's say you store them into some links like the next example and we asume we have an ID, a Name, an Age and a Location:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM persons";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while(mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<a hred="#" class="trigger" id=' . $result['id'] . '>' . $result['name'] . '</a><br />';
}
```

Now using AJAX we dispaly the results for hovering any link:

```
$('a').mouseenter(function(e) {
var myperson = $(e.target).text();
$.ajax({
url: "details.php?current=" + myperson,
success: function(html){
if(html) {
$("a").append(html);  //here you'll have to get the current hovered link- this will dispaly the info on all the links on hovering one of them
}
}
}
```

Now in the details.php page we'll do the query for the current person:

```
<?php
$currpers = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name = '" . addslashes($_GET['current']) . "'") or die(mysql_error());
$results = mysql_query($currpers);
if(mysql_fetch_array($results )) {
echo '<div class="pop-up">
      <p>
      <strong>Age:</strong>' . $results ['age'] . '<br />
      <strong>Location:</strong> ' . $results ['location'] . '
      </p>
      </div>';
}
?>
```

NOTE: I have not tested this. There might be some adjustmests but the idea is the same.